# How to click a link or button with random IDs?

Tags: webdriver, watir-webdriver

How can I ckick the button or link with a random ID?

Have this button or link a number?

For Example:

```
@b.link(:number => "1").click
```

or

```
@b.button(:number => "1").click
```

Anyone idea?

Comment: Can you add the HTML of the button/link and its parent elements? You can usually locate it via a non-random portion of the id or using its parent elements.

Comment: How would you know which button to click if you were executing the test manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works:

```
@b.link(:index => 1).click
```

Answer (score 0):

If the element is a **button**, look for some of these static elements:

- If the `name` attribute is known, try: `b.button(:name => 'submit').click`
- If the `value` (text on the button) is known, try: `b.button(:value => 'Submit').click`
- If the *button is an image*, you can use a regex on the source: `b.button(:src => /destination-url/).click`

If the element is a **link**, look for some of these static elements:

- If the `name` attribute is known, try: `b.link(:name => "link").click`
- If the `href` attribute is known, try: `b.link(:href => "http://example.com").click`
- If the text of the button is static, `b.link(:text => "Text of link here.").click`

If these don't work, you can always look to parent elements. Hopefully this helps. I'm glad to elaborate if you provide more information about your specific case.